# Selenium and HTTPUnit

Tags: selenium, functional-testing, http-unit

What's the pro's and cons for both and why should I use either of them for functional testing?

Regards,
Jonas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium is for integration testing, It will test how your web application behaves in an actual browser. This can find things that HTTPUnit cannot, e.g. browser compatibility of css and JavaScript.

HTTPUnit tests web applications by directly calling the web service and manipulating the response. This is a functional test framework as it tests what your web app does, not how it behaves across different platforms.

One advantage of HTTPUnit is that it is much quicker than Selenium. Personally I would (and do) use both. HTTPUnit for complete functional testing and Selenium for selective (not complete) integration testing to check browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

HttpUnit is very simple, extremely easy to use, and requires very little to get up and running. It's a good place to start for simple tests, however it will require more coding to create complex tests.

Selenium is more than just a library, like HttpUnit. It equips you better for more advanced, stateful tests.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium will use your browser to automate tests 
 - Selenium http://seleniumhq.org/

httpunit goes from the html specification and simulates a standards conformant browser
 - httpunit http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/

Selenium is more specific and will let you use browser specific behaviour and not limit the application under test.

With httpunit the limits are set by what httpunit supports which is far less than most browser do. E.g. the javascript capabilities are reduced to a very small set. On the other hand if your app passes httpunit tests it will probably run on quite a few browsers and environments.

So if you are interested in supporting a mininimal common set of features httpunit might be for you.